# Reference Excel worksheets dynamically

Tags: excel-2007, excel-formula

I have a problem that should be so simple, but I'm not getting my head around it. I do printed pricelists for a store and this year they've split up the part numbers into 5 worksheets instead of one.

When a user wants to print out a pricetag, she enters the = into C10, clicks the Worksheet "Pricelist" and navigates to the part number she needs.

The resulting formula for C10 is: **=Pricelist!B40**

E10 must contain more info about the part number so E10 formula is: **=VLOOKUP(C10,Pricelist!B:N,2,FALSE)**

However, now with the new worksheets she might select Worksheet "New_Items" in which case the resulting formula for C10 is: **=New_Items!B40**

How can I write the formula for E10 so that it references the same worksheet that C10 does.

I need E10 *=VLOOKUP(C10,**Pricelist**!B:N,2,FALSE)*

to automatically become *=VLOOKUP(C10,**New_Items**!B:N,2,FALSE)*

That make sense? Is that doable to have Excel modify a worksheet reference based on another cell's reference?

TIA!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes you can do this using INDIRECT() It might take a bit of work since you need to work out the name of the sheet somehow.

```
=VLOOKUP(C10, INDIRECT( Concatenate(cell-with-sheet-name, "!B:N"),TRUE ) ,2,FALSE)
```

Comment: You may need to perform extra string concatenation in other cells to determine the actual value for "cell-with-sheet-name". This can also be made easier by making all of your lookup worksheets as similiar as possible.

Comment: "...need to work out the name of the sheet somehow." Yes, what I need to do is figure out how to extract the sheet-name from C10 and have the E10 formula reference that same sheet. Can INDIRECT help me with that? Also, the data in all worksheets is strucured identically so once I'm past this hurdle I'm home-free.

Comment: If vba is enabled a simple function can use Cell.Formula parse the sheetname out and return it. For a quickstart on UDF's http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/ExcelIsFormula.htm

Answer (score 1):

Can you use vba?

If so, try this simple udf

```
Function MyLookup(ref As Range, Offset as Long) As Variant
    MyLookup = Range(ref.Formula).Offset(0, Offset)
End Function
```

Cell E10 `=MyLookup(C10, 1)`

Answer (score 1):

You could create the VBA UDF

```
Function GetShtNm(rng As Range) As String
    Application.Volatile

    If InStr(1, rng.Formula, "!") = 0 Then
        GetShtNm = vbNullString
    Else
        GetShtNm = Mid$(rng.Formula, 2, InStr(1, rng.Formula, "!") - 2)
    End If
End Function
```

and use this is the formula with the indirect provided by Eddy.

This UDF will let you dynamically track sheet name changes within the VLOOKUP INDIRECT function.