# Dynamically specify worksheet without indirect() in Excel

Tags: excel, range, worksheet, excel-2016

In my database, I have created separate worksheets for different sources of data, to make the database more structured for the users. In the summary page I created, I would like to dynamically refer to these worksheets, to easily visualize the data.

The "sheet selection" looks as follows.

[image]

`Site` should determine from which sheet the data comes. `Afdeling` and `Data` are columns in these sheets, and its values are used to find the data range (row start and row stop).

In [this excellent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18272728/dynamic-chart-range-using-indirect-that-function-is-not-valid-despite-range-hi) and answer, it is explained how to dynamically refer to a specific data range by Function, without the use of `Indirect()` ([Why I don't want indirect](https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2016/04/25/indirect-excels-most-evil-function/)). However, it does not answer how to refer to a sheet.

**Is it possible to select the worksheet in an excel file by function, without using `Indirect()`?**

Comment: Questions that only point to indirect: https://superuser.com/questions/79766/excel-vlookup-how-to-specify-dynamic-worksheet-name , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14850828/dynamic-sheet-name-in-query-in-google-spreashsheet , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7128546/reference-excel-worksheets-dynamically

Comment: It's not completely clear if you want only Excel Formula or VBA, but the other way would be to include all ranges in the formula `IF(condition, Shee1!A1, Sheet2!B2)`

Comment: I am aiming for a Formula interpretation, but if VBA is the only viable option it is also welcome. Thank you for the suggestion of the If-statements. There will be around 14.000 cells in which I need to specify the sheet, and there will be five sheets in total. Won't that amount of if-statements cause some speed issues?

Comment: Non-volatile Excel Formulas should be fastest as they are recalculated only when anything changes in the source ranges. VBA in the [Worksheet Change Event](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/events.html#worksheet-change-event) might be a bit faster than INDIRECT depending on how it's implemented. You should probably test how slow INDIRECT is before optimizing.